# React-Native FontAwesome5 how to spin icon

Tags: font-awesome, react-native, react-native-ios

I have a FontAwesome icon in my react-native application, how can i spin that icon.

```
import FontAwesome5 from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome5';
<View>
    <FontAwesome5
        name={"circle-notch"}
        style={{ fontSize: 10 }}
        spin
    />
</View>
```

Comment: Use icon like <FontAwesomeIcon icon="spinner" spin />

Comment: @VishalDhanotiya that works for Font Awesome React, but not React Native

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved?

Comment: anyone with a solution for this?